# Django @csrf_exempt decorator not working

Tags: python, django, csrf

I'm using DJango 1.8 on a linode server, and have the following view:

```
import json

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

def home_view(request):
        r = { 'response': 'OK', 'data': None }
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(r), content_type = "application/json")

@csrf_exempt
def ping(request):
        r = { 'response': 'OK', 'data': 'ping' }
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(r), content_type = "application/json")
```

My urls look like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^django/admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^django/$', home_view),
    url(r'^django/ping/$', ping),
    url(r'^django/echo/$', echo),
]
```

If I go to my linode site at 
`http://mylinodesite/django/ping/`

I get:

`{"data": "ping", "response": "OK"}`

Great.  If I use jquery and do a

`$.get("http://mylinodesite/django/ping/")`

I get

`No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

From what I understand the @csrf_exempt is supposed to get rid of the CSRF header stuff.  What gives?

Comment: I think it is a headers problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Daniel, turns out you're partially right. It's CORS but it cannot be fixed on the jQuery side.  Here's my Django view code that does what I want. Note that it adds the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to allow requests from all (`*`) for `GET` only.

This is also just a demonstration of how to do this all in one file.  One could create middleware to do this for all requests if needed, but this works and is a good example of how to do it all in one place so you can see what is going on, and [here is the full gist of the entire view file](https://gist.github.com/mikebski/9adf20dae3355c87c071):

```
def ping(request):
        r = { 'response': 'OK', 'data': 'ping' }
        response = HttpResponse("['ok']", content_type="application/json")
        response['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
        response['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'GET'

        return response
```

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing whatsoever to do with CSRF, which is for POST actions only and is enforced by Django.

You are doing a cross-domain GET action. Browsers forbid this by default because of what is called the same-origin policy: a JS script can only make requests to the same domain it is loaded from. So, you are being prevented by the browser itself.

To enable requests to named domains, you can use something called [CORS](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/), which uses a header in the request. See the [jQuery Ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: You're right about the CORS part, but jQuery is not the problem, the header needs to be added to the response (coming from Django).  See my answer for exactly how it is done.